# Netlogo. Patches categories from Landsat file

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling, gis, landsat

I am expanding a model looking at the effect of different types of fruit and fragmentation on a population of monkeys. The model reads a landsat file made up of 1's and 0s (representing forested and deforested areas) 
I need to reclassify the 1's into three kinds of trees. At the moment in the code I have the three types of trees randomly set, now I want them to be divided into percentages i.e 30 percent of the forested patches are blue, 50 percent are yellow, 20 are green. I have this atm:  I think I have to change the:

[ if value = 1 [ set value one-of tree-types ]

I tried with n-of but I can't seem to make it work.

Any suggestions?

```
to load-forest 
file-open "patch46.txt" 
let tree-types [ 1   2   3 ] 
let tree-colors [ 0 15 65 45] 
let tree-fruits [ 0 25 50 100 ] 

foreach n-values world-height [ min-pycor + ? ] 
[let num-lines ? 
foreach n-values world-width [ min-pxcor + ? ] 
[let num-cols ? 
    ask patch num-lines num-cols 
    [set value file-read 
    ] 
  ] 
] 
file-close 

ask patches 
 [ if value = 1 [ set value one-of tree-types ] 
   set pcolor item value tree-colors 
   set fruit item value tree-fruits 
 ] 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility for you would be to use the 
[`rnd:weighted-one-of`](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#rndweighted-one-of--agentset-reporter-task) primitive from the [NetLogo Rnd extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#netlogo-rnd-extension).

It works a bit like [`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of), but the probability of selecting each item can be different (i.e., weighted).

Supposing you have a list of probabilities for your different types of trees:

```
let probabilities [ 30 50 20 ]
```

You can use it as:

```
set value rnd:weighted-one-of tree-types [ item (? - 1) probabilities ]
```

Note that this will give you *on average* 30% of blue trees, 50% of yellow trees and 20% of green trees, but it might vary from run to run. Since you were already using `one-of`, which has the same effect (i.e., on average 33% of each type) I assume you are OK with that. If you wanted *exact* percentages every run, the answer would be very different.

**Side note:**

Your `tree-colors` and `tree-fruits` lists have a "dummy" `0` item just so you can use the tree type `value` directly as an index for those lists. That's confusing, and bad practice for a variety of reasons. For example, `show length tree-fruits` will print `4`. It also means that you cannot use `tree-types` and the other lists in the same [`foreach`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach) or [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) construct, e.g.: `(foreach tree-types tree-fruits [...])`. Those things may not seem like a big deal now, but they add up in the end and make your program more difficult to understand.

You should either bite the bullet and use `value - 1` as an index, or renumber your tree types to be `[ 0 1 2 ]`.

Comment: That worked great, thanks @Nicolas Payette! However I have an issue now with `file-read`, not all the files I have can be read. (maybe because they are different sizes than the world space?) I get an error message saying: The end of file has been reached error while patch 0 0 running FILE-READ called by (command task from: procedure LOAD-FOREST)
  called by (command task from: procedure LOAD-FOREST)
  called by procedure LOAD-FOREST
  called by procedure SETUP                                          Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Now you should probably accept this answer and ask a different question regarding your issue with `file-read`.